# How to check a property in search result pages in AEM or CQ?

Tags: search, aem

I am executing a query  using  query builder and getting result which are pages. now i want to check number of pages which contains a property "branch" and value is "true" and i can't include this in my query or as a predicate as i want result of all the pages whether it contains a branch property true or false. but for a different task i need the number of pages who contains branch property value true and due to performance i can't hit another query. Is there any alternative for this requirement so that i can get the number of pages in result who contains branch property true. and what will be the best way to achieve this so that performance also not get impacted.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like running a single query, and bisecting the results on a given property/predicate based on the property.  You haven't described *why* you want only a single query.

Since I am in the habit of leveraging functional programming styles (in Groovy and Java8), I would gather the query results into a Collection of resources, and then groupBy with a predicate testing your property's value.

```
PredicateGroup predicates = PredicateGroup.create(map)
Query query = queryBuilder.createQuery(predicates, session)
Map results = query.getResult().getResources()
    .collect { it as Resource }
    .groupBy { it.adaptTo(ValueMap).get("branch", false).equals() }
```

Comment: Hi, i try to work with this approach but i didn't found any collect and groupBy method after.getResources. can you please provide a detail description of this approach.

Comment: both of those methods are groovy "secret sauce" methods to help with functional programming.  If you are staying in Java, you can walk the iterator and build a list of the resources.  Then you can break the single list into 2 with filters/finds/whatever (depends on which version of Java you are using - you should be able to know how to split a list into 2 based on a predicate.